# Operating on a Completed SCons Node Graph

Tags: graph, build, callback, graphviz, scons

Does SCons provide some way of calling a user defined callback that does something interesting with the node graph after it has been completely constructed?

I want to use this for generating a GraphViz of the build graph (in Python) without relying on a potentially faulty text-output from `scons --tree=all`.

A more structured and efficient processing of the node graph that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any SCons functions published to do what you're asking. The only thing I can suggest would be to look at the source code to see how the --tree options work.

Comment: I found it in  the class `TreePrinter` in file `Main.py`.

Comment: Awesome! You may consider posting your code to the scons-users@scons.org mailing list. I would definitely like to have it :)

Comment: I'll do that. I'm thinking of adding a flag, say `--graphviz` or `--dot`, that combined with the existing `--tree` argument will output in graphviz format.